# how to customize wordpress custom walker

Tags: wordpress

in order to make the following output i used wordpress custom walker

```
class Walker_Page_Custom extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent
        <div class='nav-dropdown' style='display: block; height: 1.2534674133206636px; overflow: hidden;'>
         <div class='drop-col'>
          <img id='prod' src='#' rel='#' alt='Womenswear'>
         <ul class='level0'>
         <li id='menu-item'>

    \n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent
           </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
    \n";
}

}
```

here is my current output

```
<li id="menu-item-310" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-310">
    <a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/" class="sf-with-ul">Products Page</a>
    <div class="nav-dropdown"> <!-- first one -->
        <div class="drop-col"> <!-- first one -->
            <img id="prod" src="" rel="" alt="Womenswear">
            <ul class="level0">
                <li id="menu-item-311" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-311"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/your-account/">Your Account</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-312" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-312"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/transaction-results/">Transaction Results</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-313"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/checkout/" class="sf-with-ul">Checkout<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
                    <div class="nav-dropdown"><!-- second one -->
                        <div class="drop-col"><!-- second one -->
                            <img id="prod" src="#" rel="#" alt="Womenswear">
                            <ul class="level0">
                                <li id="menu-item-314" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-314"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/checkout/order-received/">Order Received</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-315" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-315"><a href="http://localhost/wp/products-page/checkout/pay/">Checkout ? Pay</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

if you notice, there is `<div class="nav-dropdown">` and `<div class="drop-col">` inside the first `<div class="nav-dropdown">` and `<div class="drop-col">`

so i need to change the class of the second `<div class="nav-dropdown">` and `<div class="drop-col">` to we can say `<div class="inner-nav-down">` and `<div class="inner-drop-cll">` or any other class, i don't care

any suggests to edit this custom walker to do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $inner = $depth ? 'inner-' : '';
    $output .= "\n$indent
        <div class='".$inner."nav-dropdown' style='display: block; height: 1.2534674133206636px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <div class='".$inner."drop-col'>
        <img id='prod' src='#' rel='#' alt='Womenswear'>
        <ul class='level0'>
        <li id='menu-item'>

    \n";
}
```

Comment: Also, just so you're aware, pixels (px) are the smallest unit of measurement in styling. Decimal places are NOT honored when measuring in pixels.

Comment: worked like crazy, answered, but if you have time, could you please explain what happened a little bit?, if you don't have time, that is fine

Comment: Sure. The $depth argument is a simple integer that contains a numerical representation of the current level of your walker. For instance: Parent=0, Child=1, Grandchild=2, and so forth. The $inner variable is a simple ternary operator that states that it will be set equal to the string 'inner-' if $depth is greater than 0, otherwise it will be set to the empty string ''. Integers greater than 0 evaluate to true while integers less than or equal to 0 evaluate to false, so I left out the greater-than 0 part of the conditional.

Comment: that is awesome, how smoothly that explain was, really i am sooo happy because i asked you to explain, and more happier that i read this answer, i not in a level allows me to rate this answer, but thank you, really